# custom post type - use default or create new?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm building a website that will only have one post type called Work. This post type will need a field as well. Should I just use the default post type (post) and use custom fields or hide the default post type and create a brand new one called Work? If the former, is there a way to change "Post" to "Work" in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a new post type and remove the regular post, just rename post to work,

```
add_filter('gettext','rename_post_to_work');
function rename_post_to_work( $input ) {
    if( is_admin() && 'post' == $input || 'Post' == $post_type )
        return 'Work';
    return $input;
}
```